# PostGis Extension Installed in AlFresco PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, alfresco, postgis

I am working in a project that uses AlFresco-4.2.c as the main program in Ubuntu 16.04, and also uses geoserver in tomcat configured with PostgreSQL.

The problem is that I have been searching for a week about how to install the postgis extension in the own postgresql of alfresco. I have searched in the official documentation of alfresco(http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/tasks/postgresql-config.html) and other forums, but I have found nothing about extensions.

Do you know a way of installing it?

I have tried to use apt-get and the installer of DBEnterprises, but none of that worked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you've followed, but here is what I would have done.

As quickly read from the [PostGis](http://postgis.net/install/) page, it's a separate extension on PostgreSQL.
So you'll need to forget about Alfresco for one second, find your local PostgreSQL installation.

It's mostly bundled by Alfresco in the alfresco folder, so e.g. /opt/alfresco-4.2.c/postgresql and the data resides /opt/alfresco-4.2.c/alf_data/postgresql.

If this doesn't work for you, just do the following:

1. Create a dump file from the current PostgreSQL
2. Install a PostgreSQL distro from Ubuntu (check the version numbers)
3. Install the PostGIS extension
4. Import the dump file

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. What i ended up doing was installing the postgresql and postgis in local, and then unite it with the AlFresco. Anyway, i hope it woks.

Comment: would help better if you explain with details. How you did this "unite with Alfresco"